# Use a computed switch in CSS to define top property of v-img

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to define the top property of a v-img depending on the current breakpoint of the window.

I wanted to define it like that:

```
<v-img contain id="logo-transparent" :top="logoTop" :width="logoWidth" :src="logoTransparent" class="hidden-xs-only"></v-img>
```

with the computed property looking like that:

```
logoTop(){
            switch (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name) {
                case 'xl': return "-4%"
                case 'lg': return "-6%"
                case 'md': return "-8%"
                case 'sm': return "-8%"
                case 'xs': return 0
                default:
                    return "-4%"
            }
        },
```

and the CSS like this:

```
#logo-transparent{
  z-index: 1;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -1%;
}
```

but the problem is that v-img doesn't have the top property.

I wanted to use my computed function to define the CSS of the image like this:

```
logoTop(){
            return {
                "--top-property" : switch (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name) {
                                    case 'xl': return 400
                                    case 'lg': return 300
                                    case 'md': return 300
                                    case 'sm': return 200
                                    case 'xs': return 0
                                    default:
                                        return 400
                                }
            }
            
        },
```

to be able to use it like this in the css:

```css
top : var(--top-property)
```

but it seems that I can't use a switch in that case.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`switch` doesn't return anything. You should use a variable like so

```js
logoTop() {
    let topProperty;
    switch (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name) {
        case 'xl':
            topProperty =  400;
            break;
        case 'lg':
        case 'md':
            topProperty =  300;
            break;
        case 'sm':
            topProperty =  200;
            break;
        case 'xs':
            topProperty =  0;
            break;
        default:
            topProperty = 400;
    }
    return {
        "--top-property" : topProperty
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original `logoTop` computed property would work to set the `v-img`'s `top` position in a [style binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1):

```html
<template>
  <v-img :style="{ top: logoTop }" ... />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    logoTop() {
      switch (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name) {
        case 'xl': return "-4%"
        case 'lg': return "-6%"
        case 'md': return "-8%"
        case 'sm': return "-8%"
        case 'xs': return 0
        default: return "-4%"
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/abWebEM?editors=1010)